Plotly - highlight connected nodes in graph
I want to make a network graph in plotly. In that graph I would love to have the following functionality:

Whenever I hover over a node I would love to see the undirected edges and the connected nodes to be highlighted (e.g. bold edges and bigger nodes).

Solutions I found on the web aren't really helpful because they either handle different kind of (non-network) plots and/or are rather undetailed. I would be happy with any solution that fullfills my needs. I tried to handle this issue with Figure Widgets, which didn't work out. Here is some basic code that I would like to extend:
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Define the nodes and edges
nodes = ['Node 1', 'Node 2', 'Node 3']
edges = [('Node 1', 'Node 2'), ('Node 2', 'Node 3'), ('Node 3', 'Node 1'), ('Node 1', 'Node 3'), ('Node 2', 'Node 1')]

# Position of the nodes for visualization
positions = {'Node 1': (1, 2), 'Node 2': (2, 1), 'Node 3': (3, 2)}

# Create a scatter plot for the nodes
node_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=[positions[node][0] for node in nodes],
    y=[positions[node][1] for node in nodes],
    text=nodes,
    mode='markers+text',
    marker=dict(size=10, color='LightSkyBlue'),
    hoverinfo='text'
)

# Create a trace for the edges
edge_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=[],
    y=[],
    line=dict(width=2, color='Grey'),
    hoverinfo='none',
    mode='lines'
)

for edge in edges:
    x0, y0 = positions[edge[0]]
    x1, y1 = positions[edge[1]]
    edge_trace['x'] += (x0, x1, None)
    edge_trace['y'] += (y0, y1, None)

# Create the Plotly figure
fig = go.Figure(data=[edge_trace, node_trace],
                layout=go.Layout(
                    title='Network Graph',
                    titlefont_size=16,
                    showlegend=False,
                    hovermode='closest',
                    margin=dict(b=20, l=5, r=5, t=40),
                    xaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False),
                    yaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False))
               )

fig.show()

As I described, I tried out FigureWidgets, which did not work for me.

I now switched over to pyvis, which has all the features I want natively.
